# Log4j custom appender doesn't "log" TRACE event

Tags: java, logging, log4j, appender

I am having an odd issue with a custom appender I am writing, it will not log `trace` `LoggingEvents`.

The purpose of the appender, is an experiment in writing appenders, and the use of a couple of other technologies (Gradle and assertJ for example), a self learning exercise, and to see if I can improve on using Mockito for capture of log messages during testing.
I want the appender to capture all log levels and to that end I have implemented `AppenderSkeleton` and I set the threshold to `ALL` in the constructor.

During debug it doesn't even appear as if `AppenderSkeleton.doAppend` is evening being called.

Is trace different to the other levels somehow?

I have tried with and without SLF4J as my log manager, interestingly SLF4J doesn't seem to support fatal.
Log4J version is 1.2.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the level of the logger using the custom appender is also "trace"

Comment: So simple! I didn't think I need to set the logger level as I was setting it in the appender.
Thanks